# Flutter : Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter

I have a scenario wherein I check the value of SharePreferences based on the value it will redirect the user to HomePage or LandingPage. I am not sure where did I got wrong? but I am getting this error below: I guess its not getting the context right any idea how do I get it?.

> Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
>   E/flutter (11533): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:credit/src/pages/landing.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:credit/src/pages/credit/home.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _LoadingPageState createState() => _LoadingPageState();
}

class _LoadingPageState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserStatus().then((userStatus) {
      if (userStatus == null) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return LandingPage();
        }));
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return HomePage();
        }));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ));
  }
}

Future<String> getUserStatus() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String userStatus = prefs.getString('userstatus');
  print("==On Load Check ==");
  print(userStatus);
  return userStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Navigator.of(context)` framework goes up in widget tree attached to provided `context` and tries to find the closest `Navigator`.

The widget tree you showed does not have one, so you need to include `Navigator` in the widget tree.
Easiest option is to use `MaterialApp` with your widget passed as `home`. `MaterialApp` is creating navigator inside itself. (`CupertinoApp` does it too)

Updated code from original example:

```dart
import 'package:credit/src/pages/landing.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:credit/src/pages/credit/home.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoadingPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoadingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoadingPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _LoadingPageState createState() => _LoadingPageState();
}

class _LoadingPageState extends State<LoadingPage> { // note type update
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserStatus().then((userStatus) {
      if (userStatus == null) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return LandingPage();
        }));
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return HomePage();
        }));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ));
  }
}

Future<String> getUserStatus() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String userStatus = prefs.getString('userstatus');
  print("==On Load Check ==");
  print(userStatus);
  return userStatus;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't quite get it. Can you please help with the code for a better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my code from

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: white,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                HomeScreen(title: 'Demo Home')));
                  },
                  child: Text('Open Home Screen'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

To

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Demo App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: white,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: InitScreen());
  }
}

class InitScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              HomeScreen(title: 'Demo Home')));
                },
                child: Text('Open Home Screen'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**What changed?**

> Create a separate widget for *home* code in *MyApp* with *InitScreen*

**What was the issue?**

> When we try to push Route by using Navigator.of(context), flutter will
> try to find Navigator in the widget tree of the given context. In the
> initial code, there was no widget that has Navigator. So, create a
> separate widget for home code. And the MaterialApp widget in MyApp
> will have Navigator.